# Endless loop in afterSave function in yii2

Tags: yii2

I have an afterSave function in my model, the function executes, but in an endless loop. what could be the reason? 
The function inserts the data into my DB, but in multiple rows.
thanks.

my function:

```
public function afterSave($insert)
{

    $modelProject = projects::find()
    ->where(['status' => 2])
    ->one();
    $idProject = $modelProject->pId;

    $candidateforproject = new candidateforproject();
    // $candidateforproject->id = 3;
    $candidateforproject->idProject = $idProject;
    $candidateforproject->idCandidate = $this->prId;
    $candidateforproject->idQuestionnaire = $this->id;
    $candidateforproject->idStatus = 0;
    $candidateforproject->insert();

    $answerOne = questionsgrades::findOne($this->answer1);
    $grade1 = $answerOne->grade;

    $answerTow = questionsgrades::findOne($this->answer2);
    $grade2 = $answerTow->grade;

    $answerThree = questionsgrades::findOne($this->answer3);
    $grade3 = $answerThree->grade;

    $answerFour = questionsgrades::findOne($this->answer4);
    $grade4 = $answerFour->grade;

    $answerFive = questionsgrades::findOne($this->answer5);
    $grade5 = $answerFive->grade;

    $grade = $grade1 + $grade2 + $grade3 + $grade4 + $grade5;

    $this->degree=$grade; 
    $this->save(['degree']);

    }
    return parent::afterSave($insert);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that you are using $this->save(); in AfterSave action. This will cause calling AfterSave() again. So here is the place with loop.

Possible fix is to use $this->update(); instead of $this->save();

but, honestly, I think you should remaster you logic architecture.